# ReactJS chartjs changes data every time it is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

here I want to ask about chartjs.

So, I have a case where there is a user who wants to change the data in the Bar Chart.

When the user clicks on the data in the tree menu, the data in the bar chart will
automatically change according to what the user clicked on.

I've tried to make it, like the code below =

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import {
  Accordion,
  AccordionItem,
  AccordionItemHeading,
  AccordionItemButton,
  AccordionItemPanel,
} from "react-accessible-accordion";
import { MdKeyboardArrowDown } from "react-icons/md";
import {
  getBuildingOLDallProvinsi,
  getBuildingOLDallKota,
  getBuildingOLDallKecamatan,
  getBuildingOLDallKelurahan,
} from "../../../service/building";

import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from "chart.js";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);

const Data = () => {
  const [dataProvinsi, setDataProvinsi] = useState([]);
  const [dataKota, setDataKota] = useState([]);
  const [dataKecamatan, setDataKecamatan] = useState([]);
  const [dataKelurahan, setDataKelurahan] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isLoadingKota, setIsLoadingKota] = useState(false);
  const [isLoadingKecamatan, setIsLoadingKecamatan] = useState(false);
  const provinsiRef = useRef([]);
  const kotaRef = useRef([]);
  const kecamatanRef = useRef([]);

  const getDataAllProvinsi = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    getBuildingOLDallProvinsi()
      .then((resolve) => {
        setDataProvinsi(resolve);
        console.log();
      })
      .catch((reject) => {
        console.log(reject);
      })
      .finally(setIsLoading(false));
  };

  const handleProvinsi = async (index) => {
    try {
      const provinsi = provinsiRef.current[index].dataset.prov;
      setIsLoading(true);
      const result = await getBuildingOLDallKota(provinsi);
      setDataKota(result);
      console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("salah");
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const handleKota = async (provinsi, index) => {
    try {
      const kota = kotaRef.current[index].dataset.city;
      setIsLoadingKota(true);
      const result = await getBuildingOLDallKecamatan(provinsi, kota);
      setDataKecamatan(result);
      console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("salah");
    } finally {
      setIsLoadingKota(false);
    }
  };

  const handleKecamatan = async (provinsi, kota, index) => {
    try {
      const kecamatan = kecamatanRef.current[index].dataset.camat;
      setIsLoadingKecamatan(true);
      const result = await getBuildingOLDallKelurahan(
        provinsi,
        kota,
        kecamatan
      );
      setDataKelurahan(result);
      console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("salah");
      console.log(error);
    } finally {
      setIsLoadingKecamatan(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getDataAllProvinsi();
  }, [dataKota, dataKecamatan, dataKelurahan]);

  const colorCode = "#0066FF";
  const colorFont = "#8E9093";
  const state = {
    data: {
      dataProv: {
        labels: dataProvinsi.map((o) => o.provinsi),
        datasets: [
          {
            fill: true,
            label: null,
            backgroundColor: colorCode,
            borderColor: colorCode,
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderRadius: 12,
            data: dataProvinsi.map((o) => o.total_building),
          },
        ],
      },
      datakota: {
        labels: dataKota.map((o) => o.kota),
        datasets: [
          {
            fill: true,
            label: null,
            backgroundColor: colorCode,
            borderColor: colorCode,
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderRadius: 12,
            data: dataKota.map((o) => o.total_building),
          },
        ],
      },
      dataCamat: {
        labels: dataKecamatan.map((o) => o.kecamatan),
        datasets: [
          {
            fill: true,
            label: null,
            backgroundColor: colorCode,
            borderColor: colorCode,
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderRadius: 12,
            data: dataKecamatan.map((o) => o.total_building),
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    options: {
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          display: false,
          labels: {
            font: {
              color: colorFont,
            },
          },
        },
      },
      scales: {
        x: {
          grid: {
            display: false,
          },
          beginAtZero: false,
          ticks: {
            color: colorFont,
          },
        },
        y: {
          grid: {
            display: false,
          },
          beginAtZero: true,
          ticks: {
            color: colorFont,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };

  const plugins = [
    {
      beforeDraw: function (chart) {
        if (chart.chartArea) {
          let ctx = chart.ctx;
          let chartArea = chart.chartArea;
          let barArray = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data;

          ctx.fillStyle = "#B2D1FF85";

          for (let i = 0; i < barArray.length; i++) {
            const { x, width } = barArray[i];

            ctx.fillRect(
              x - width / 2,
              chartArea.top,
              width,
              chartArea.bottom - chartArea.top
            );
          }
        }
      },
    },
  ];

  const changeData2 = () => {
    const newData = [state.data.datakota];
    setDataKota(newData);
    console.log(newData);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="mx-auto mt-8 w-[70rem] h-[32rem] bg-white px-5 py-3 md:px-8 md:py-5 rounded-xl drop-shadow-xl">
        <h1 className="font-bold text-lg mb-4">Diagram Data</h1>
        <Bar
          type={"bar"}
          height={120}
          data={state.data.dataProv}
          options={state.options}
          plugins={plugins}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="mx-auto my-8 w-[70rem] bg-white px-5 py-3 md:px-8 md:py-5 rounded-md drop-shadow-xl">
        <h1 className="font-bold text-lg">Data Per Daerah</h1>
        <div className="flex justify-between mt-6">
          <h3 className="font-bold">Nama Daerah</h3>
          <h3 className="font-bold">TOTAL BUILDING</h3>
        </div>
        <Accordion allowZeroExpanded>
          {dataProvinsi.map((provinsi, index) => (
            <AccordionItem className="p-1" key={index}>
              <AccordionItemHeading
                onClick={() => {
                  handleProvinsi(index);
                  changeData2()
                }}
              >
                <AccordionItemButton>
                  <div className="w-full inline-flex justify-between items-center">
                    <div className="inline-flex items-center gap-2">
                      <div>
                        <MdKeyboardArrowDown size={20} />
                      </div>
                      <div
                        ref={(ref) => provinsiRef.current.push(ref)}
                        data-prov={provinsi?.provinsi}
                      >
                        {provinsi?.provinsi}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>{provinsi?.total_building}</div>
                  </div>
                </AccordionItemButton>
              </AccordionItemHeading>
              <AccordionItemPanel className="ml-4">
                <Accordion className="flex flex-col gap-2" allowZeroExpanded>
                  {isLoading ? (
                    <div role="status">
                      <svg
                        className="inline mr-2 w-8 h-8 text-gray-200 animate-spin dark:text-gray-600 fill-red-600"
                        viewBox="0 0 100 101"
                        fill="none"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      >
                        <path
                          d="M100 50.5908C100 78.2051 77.6142 100.591 50 100.591C22.3858 100.591 0 78.2051 0 50.5908C0 22.9766 22.3858 0.59082 50 0.59082C77.6142 0.59082 100 22.9766 100 50.5908ZM9.08144 50.5908C9.08144 73.1895 27.4013 91.5094 50 91.5094C72.5987 91.5094 90.9186 73.1895 90.9186 50.5908C90.9186 27.9921 72.5987 9.67226 50 9.67226C27.4013 9.67226 9.08144 27.9921 9.08144 50.5908Z"
                          fill="currentColor"
                        />
                        <path
                          d="M93.9676 39.0409C96.393 38.4038 97.8624 35.9116 97.0079 33.5539C95.2932 28.8227 92.871 24.3692 89.8167 20.348C85.8452 15.1192 80.8826 10.7238 75.2124 7.41289C69.5422 4.10194 63.2754 1.94025 56.7698 1.05124C51.7666 0.367541 46.6976 0.446843 41.7345 1.27873C39.2613 1.69328 37.813 4.19778 38.4501 6.62326C39.0873 9.04874 41.5694 10.4717 44.0505 10.1071C47.8511 9.54855 51.7191 9.52689 55.5402 10.0491C60.8642 10.7766 65.9928 12.5457 70.6331 15.2552C75.2735 17.9648 79.3347 21.5619 82.5849 25.841C84.9175 28.9121 86.7997 32.2913 88.1811 35.8758C89.083 38.2158 91.5421 39.6781 93.9676 39.0409Z"
                          fill="currentFill"
                        />
                      </svg>
                      <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                    </div>
                  ) : (
                    dataKota.map((kota, index) => (
                      <AccordionItem className="p-1" key={kota?.id}>
                        <AccordionItemHeading
                          onClick={() => {
                            handleKota(provinsi?.provinsi, index);
                          }}
                        >
                          <AccordionItemButton>
                            <div className="w-full inline-flex justify-between items-center">
                              <div className="inline-flex items-center gap-2">
                                <div>
                                  <MdKeyboardArrowDown size={20} />
                                </div>
                                <div
                                  ref={(ref) => kotaRef.current.push(ref)}
                                  data-city={kota?.kota}
                                >
                                  {kota?.kota}
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div>{kota?.total_building}</div>
                            </div>
                          </AccordionItemButton>
                        </AccordionItemHeading>
                        <AccordionItemPanel className="ml-8">
                          <Accordion
                            className="flex flex-col gap-2"
                            allowZeroExpanded
                          >
                            {isLoadingKota ? (
                              <div role="status">
                                <svg
                                  className="inline mr-2 w-8 h-8 text-gray-200 animate-spin dark:text-gray-600 fill-red-600"
                                  viewBox="0 0 100 101"
                                  fill="none"
                                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                >
                                  <path
                                    d="M100 50.5908C100 78.2051 77.6142 100.591 50 100.591C22.3858 100.591 0 78.2051 0 50.5908C0 22.9766 22.3858 0.59082 50 0.59082C77.6142 0.59082 100 22.9766 100 50.5908ZM9.08144 50.5908C9.08144 73.1895 27.4013 91.5094 50 91.5094C72.5987 91.5094 90.9186 73.1895 90.9186 50.5908C90.9186 27.9921 72.5987 9.67226 50 9.67226C27.4013 9.67226 9.08144 27.9921 9.08144 50.5908Z"
                                    fill="currentColor"
                                  />
                                  <path
                                    d="M93.9676 39.0409C96.393 38.4038 97.8624 35.9116 97.0079 33.5539C95.2932 28.8227 92.871 24.3692 89.8167 20.348C85.8452 15.1192 80.8826 10.7238 75.2124 7.41289C69.5422 4.10194 63.2754 1.94025 56.7698 1.05124C51.7666 0.367541 46.6976 0.446843 41.7345 1.27873C39.2613 1.69328 37.813 4.19778 38.4501 6.62326C39.0873 9.04874 41.5694 10.4717 44.0505 10.1071C47.8511 9.54855 51.7191 9.52689 55.5402 10.0491C60.8642 10.7766 65.9928 12.5457 70.6331 15.2552C75.2735 17.9648 79.3347 21.5619 82.5849 25.841C84.9175 28.9121 86.7997 32.2913 88.1811 35.8758C89.083 38.2158 91.5421 39.6781 93.9676 39.0409Z"
                                    fill="currentFill"
                                  />
                                </svg>
                                <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                              </div>
                            ) : (
                              dataKecamatan.map((kecamatan, index) => (
                                <AccordionItem
                                  className="p-1"
                                  key={kecamatan?.id}
                                >
                                  <AccordionItemHeading
                                    onClick={() => {
                                      handleKecamatan(
                                        provinsi?.provinsi,
                                        kota?.kota,
                                        index
                                      );
                                    }}
                                  >
                                    <AccordionItemButton>
                                      <div className="w-full inline-flex justify-between items-center">
                                        <div className="inline-flex items-center gap-2">
                                          <div>
                                            <MdKeyboardArrowDown size={20} />
                                          </div>
                                          <div
                                            ref={(ref) =>
                                              kecamatanRef.current.push(ref)
                                            }
                                            data-camat={kecamatan?.kecamatan}
                                          >
                                            {kecamatan?.kecamatan}
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>{kecamatan?.total_building}</div>
                                      </div>
                                    </AccordionItemButton>
                                  </AccordionItemHeading>
                                  <AccordionItemPanel className="ml-12">
                                    <Accordion
                                      className="flex flex-col gap-2"
                                      allowZeroExpanded
                                    >
                                      {isLoadingKecamatan ? (
                                        <div role="status">
                                          <svg
                                            className="inline mr-2 w-8 h-8 text-gray-200 animate-spin dark:text-gray-600 fill-red-600"
                                            viewBox="0 0 100 101"
                                            fill="none"
                                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                          >
                                            <path
                                              d="M100 50.5908C100 78.2051 77.6142 100.591 50 100.591C22.3858 100.591 0 78.2051 0 50.5908C0 22.9766 22.3858 0.59082 50 0.59082C77.6142 0.59082 100 22.9766 100 50.5908ZM9.08144 50.5908C9.08144 73.1895 27.4013 91.5094 50 91.5094C72.5987 91.5094 90.9186 73.1895 90.9186 50.5908C90.9186 27.9921 72.5987 9.67226 50 9.67226C27.4013 9.67226 9.08144 27.9921 9.08144 50.5908Z"
                                              fill="currentColor"
                                            />
                                            <path
                                              d="M93.9676 39.0409C96.393 38.4038 97.8624 35.9116 97.0079 33.5539C95.2932 28.8227 92.871 24.3692 89.8167 20.348C85.8452 15.1192 80.8826 10.7238 75.2124 7.41289C69.5422 4.10194 63.2754 1.94025 56.7698 1.05124C51.7666 0.367541 46.6976 0.446843 41.7345 1.27873C39.2613 1.69328 37.813 4.19778 38.4501 6.62326C39.0873 9.04874 41.5694 10.4717 44.0505 10.1071C47.8511 9.54855 51.7191 9.52689 55.5402 10.0491C60.8642 10.7766 65.9928 12.5457 70.6331 15.2552C75.2735 17.9648 79.3347 21.5619 82.5849 25.841C84.9175 28.9121 86.7997 32.2913 88.1811 35.8758C89.083 38.2158 91.5421 39.6781 93.9676 39.0409Z"
                                              fill="currentFill"
                                            />
                                          </svg>
                                          <span className="sr-only">
                                            Loading...
                                          </span>
                                        </div>
                                      ) : (
                                        dataKelurahan.map((item, index) => (
                                          <AccordionItem
                                            className="p-1"
                                            key={index}
                                          >
                                            <AccordionItemHeading>
                                              <AccordionItemButton>
                                                <div className="w-full inline-flex justify-between items-center">
                                                  <div className="inline-flex items-center gap-2">
                                                    <div>
                                                      <MdKeyboardArrowDown
                                                        size={20}
                                                      />
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div>{item?.kelurahan}</div>
                                                  </div>
                                                  <div>
                                                    {item?.total_building}
                                                  </div>
                                                </div>
                                              </AccordionItemButton>
                                            </AccordionItemHeading>
                                          </AccordionItem>
                                        ))
                                      )}
                                    </Accordion>
                                  </AccordionItemPanel>
                                </AccordionItem>
                              ))
                            )}
                          </Accordion>
                        </AccordionItemPanel>
                      </AccordionItem>
                    ))
                  )}
                </Accordion>
              </AccordionItemPanel>
            </AccordionItem>
          ))}
        </Accordion>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Data;
```

But still can't, can you help me?

Thank you very much, I appreciate your answers and your help.

For more details, it's in the video, you can watch it.
https://s3.amazonaws.com/tempmedia.tumblr.com/7acafbf9ff21c65698642e532303fd8c/97nwuqs8m7gog40k0o0g0kocc_tumblr_tmp.mp4

Comment: until now it hasn't been solved. please help me, dude. thank you

Comment: Instead of passing all the code can you give the code piece where is the problem and try to explain your code piece by piece? It will take forever to understand all code above